# Pandas DataFrame + визуализация

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, графика

уважаемые знатоки !
В очередной раз надеюсь на Вашу помощь.
Имеется датафрейм вида :

```
0       1  UA11111   Событие1  2018-10-01  Место1  
1       2  UA22222   Событие1  2018-10-01  Место2  
2       3  UA11111   Событие2  2018-10-02  Место2  
3       4  UA22222   Событие2  2018-10-03  Место2  
4       5  UA11111   Событие3  2018-10-04  Место1  
5       6  UA22222   Событие4  2018-10-05  Место1
```

С помощью какой библиотеки я могу нарисовать нечто такое :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: готовой библиотеки не знаю, похоже придется ручками... посмотрите [этот вопрос и ответы на него](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772421/how-to-plot-events-on-time-on-using-matplotlib)

Comment: MaxU, спасибо за отклик и ссылку, буду пробовать.